# Practice with sharepoint 2010 online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to learn sharepoint 2010. To setup environment it costs nearly 20,000 INR for me. Instead of that is there any site to give access to their machines and give an opportunity to practice the sharepoint development and features etc. I know this is not relevant question here to ask, but this is only site in which masters can give quick response.

Thanks

Comment: I am also searching for this one. Please help any one

Comment: Where to ask such type of questions?

Comment: There is currently no site on the Stack Exchange network on which this in an on-topic question.

Comment: yeah ofcourse, but if any one knows it is good to help me out.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one. I too just found it.
[Virtual Machine](https://cmg.vlabcenter.com/default.aspx?moduleid=dd8d658f-373c-4ce0-9c1d-dd25847e846c)

Here we are able to access the sharepoint 2010 and visual studio as well.

Comment: Love how much hidden stuff there is everywhere

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play with SharePoint without the costs of setting up your own SharePoint environment, you might have some luck with Office365

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/sharepoint-online.aspx#fbid=QOhSDqk0-P4

EDIT: Looks like that link isn't around anymore, if you are reading this now then try here:
https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-collaboration-software

Comment: oh.. great.. Shall i practice share point in that after buying user licence for $4?

Answer (score 2):

Office 365 will give you some end user functionality testing but if you are going to be doing sharepoint development you really need a localized environment. Sandboxed solutions will get you far but only a portion of what it takes to truly do sharepoint development.

I'd suggest starting with sharepoint foundation on a localized environment. This can be installed on a windows 7 computer with SQL Server express and does not require any licensing other than the host machine of windows 7 and can run with 4gb of memory.

Comment: Agreed. For development, go with SharePoint Foundation. If you have access to a computer that is powerful enough and have the time to set it up, this is the best way.

Comment: SharePoint Foundation requires a server operating system, as far as I could read online. Like Windows Server 2008, 2012 etc.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cloudshare.com/

Create Pro Account which is free for 14 days

set up your own environment by selecting suitable templates

Answer (score 0):

Cloud share is best to practice for 14 days otherwise setting up VM is a good option

Regards,
Harika